# Imagemagick PHP Plasma Seeding/Reuse?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, fractals

I want to be able to reuse the randomly generated plasma fractal patterns/colors from my PHP Imagemagick script.

Here's the code for the plasma fractal:

```
   $test = new Imagick();
    $test->newPseudoImage(100, 100, 'plasma:fractal');
    $img->compositeImage($test, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, 0, 0);
```

The problem with this code is that it randomizes and I can't reuse a previously generatern pattern.

The effect I want could be achieved by seeding. Does anyone know how to do seed a plasma fractal with PHP Imagemagick? 
All I could find was a MagickCore code for lower level languages.

Any other ways, besides saving the images onto the server, that I could go about reusing randomly generated fractals?

Comment: I do not know if Imagick has that feature. But in ImageMagick, you random noise is controlled with -seed XXX. In Imagick, perhaps you can control that with an attribute. Sorry, I do not know Imagick well. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#seed

Comment: See also https://imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#plasma_seeded

Comment: Try Imagick::setImageAttribute ( 'seed' , '100' ) and see if that works. Put it right after new Imagick();

Comment: Thank you. I tried setImageAttribute, it broke the image when using it after  $test = new Imagick(); and before $test->newPseudoImage(100, 100, 'plasma:fractal');. If used after $test->newPseudoImage(100, 100, 'plasma:fractal');, it didn't have any effect. I tried various other things such as setImageProperty, no luck yet. Will post if I find a solution.

Comment: How about setImageArtifact?  Otherwise, I would assume that Imagick has not implemented it. The seed must be set before any random image is generated. If all else fails use PHP exec() with a command line command to create the seed and plasma image.